# insert_many in pymongo not persisting

Tags: pymongo

I'm having some issues with persisting documents with pymongo when using `insert_many`.

I'm handing over a list of dicts to `insert_many` and it works fine from inside the same script that does the inserting. Less so once the script has finished.

```py
def row_to_doc(row):
    rowdict = row.to_dict()
    for key in rowdict:
        val = rowdict[key]
        if type(val) == float or type(val) == np.float64:
            if np.isnan(val):
                # If we want a SQL style document collection
                rowdict[key] = None
                # If we want a NoSQL style document collection
                # del rowdict[key]
    return rowdict

def dataframe_to_collection(df):
    n = len(df)
    doc_list = []
    for k in range(n):
        doc_list.append(row_to_doc(df.iloc[k]))
    return doc_list

def get_mongodb_client(host="localhost", port=27017):
    return MongoClient(host, port)

def create_collection(client):
    db = client["material"]
    return db["master-data"]

def add_docs_to_mongo(collection, doc_list):
    collection.insert_many(doc_list)

def main():
    client = get_mongodb_client()
    csv_fname = "some_csv_fname.csv"
    df = get_clean_csv(csv_fname)
    doc_list = dataframe_to_collection(df)

    collection = create_collection(client)
    add_docs_to_mongo(collection, doc_list)

    test_doc = collection.find_one({"MATERIAL": "000000000000000001"})
```

When I open up another python REPL and start looking through the `client.material.master_data` collection with `collection.find_one({"MATERIAL": "000000000000000001"})` or `collection.count_documents({})` I get None for the `find_one` and 0 for the `count_documents`.

Is there a step where I need to call some method to persist the data to disk? `db.collection.save()` in the mongo client API *sounds* like what I need but it's just another way of inserting documents from what I have read. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fell back to [collection.insert_one(doc) for doc in doc_list]. Still not persisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was getting my collection via `client.db_name.collection_name` and it wasn't getting the same collection I was creating with my code. `client.db_name["collection-name"]` solved my issue. Weird.